# How to use images from a hyperlink created in an array and put them on the same page using _GET

Tags: php

I'm trying to open images by using hyperlinks created by an array and open them on the same page using get in an image element

this is for a school assignment and I've tried to change $items in the get to $everything

```
$everything = scandir("img/back"); //scans the directory
$everything = array_splice($everything, 2); //trims off the first 2
//print_r($everything); //prints it out on the page might not be required

foreach ($everything as $items) { //loops so it prints everything in array
    echo "<a href='img/back/$items'>$items</a> <br>"; //makes hyperlink needs img/back to get directed towards img map before it can open the files shown by scandir

}
if (isset($_GET[$items])){
    echo "<img src='img/back/$items' alt='link'>$items";
    } else {
}
```

I expect the output to echo the image I've clicked on from the hyperlink in the array, but it opens the image in a new tab

Comment: `isset($_GET[$items]` What are you doing with $_GET variable along with dynamic keys and Why? 
Your `IF` condition is supposed to be within the loop.

Comment: We're basically being thought to make a filebrowser in PHP and in the previous assignment we had to make an array with scandir and turn those in hyperlinks to a set of images we've gotten this is basically the follow up and we have to maintain the code and i got the tip of a fellow student to use the if set of the code